# Merge two JSONs together without duplicate in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two sets of data sources:

- External data source 1

```py
d1 = [
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jim", "role": ["Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jerry", "role": ["Admin"]},
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
]
```

- External data source 2

```py
d2 = [
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jim", "role": ["Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jenny", "role": ["Admin"]},
]
```

I am looking to combine the two lists into one to view all the permissions each user has. So this is what it will look like:

```py
[
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jim", "role": ["Manager", "Admin", "Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jerry", "role": ["Admin"]},
    {"user": "jenny", "role": ["Admin"]},
]
```

And not:

```py
result = [
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jim", "role": ["Manager", "Admin", "Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jerry", "role": ["Admin"]},
    {"user": "jenny", "role": ["Admin"]},
]
```

If this was Java I would have used a Hashmap to merge the two data sources (small data sources) so that I can prevent duplicates.

What's the equivalent for a hashmap in Python 3 to achieve my end results?

Comment: Are all user names guaranteed to be unique in your list (?) of dictionaries? Also, your data source 1 does not represent a valid Python or JSON structure

Comment: Yes they are unique. Json structure might not be valid since it's a sample.. But thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the two lists and iterate through them. If the user has already been added to the output dictionary, add any new role(s) to what are already there; if not, create a new entry. I've converted the `role` lists to [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), so they'll automatically exclude duplicates.

[`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) is used only to break the result onto multiple lines for readability.

```
from pprint import pprint

output = {}

for entry in d1 + d2:
    user, role = entry['user'], entry['role']
    if user in output:
        output[user] |= set(role)
    else:
        output[user] = set(role)

pprint(output)
```

This will create a dictionary whose keys are the usernames and whose values are sets of roles:

```
{'gill': {'Manager', 'Admin', 'Viewer'},
 'jack': {'Manager', 'Admin', 'Viewer'},
 'jenny': {'Admin'},
 'jerry': {'Admin'},
 'jim': {'Manager', 'Admin', 'Viewer'}}
```

Personally I think that's already a very expressive and Pythonic data structure for a group of uniquely named users, each of whom has a number of non-duplicated roles. But it can be converted to the format you show via a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
output = [{'user': user, 'role': list(role)} for user, role in output.items()]
```

This approach can be improved with a couple of tools from the standard library:

1. You can "automate" the add-if-there-else-create procedure by using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).
2. Using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) iterates through the two lists without having to copy them to a third list in memory. This is unlikely to have a significant impact unless your lists are very large, but it's a good practice to learn.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint

output = defaultdict(set)

for entry in chain(d1, d2):
    user, role = entry['user'], entry['role']
    output[user] |= set(role)

output = [{'user': user, 'role': list(role)} for user, role in output.items()]
pprint(output, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'user': 'jack', 'role': ['Viewer', 'Manager', 'Admin']},
 {'user': 'jim', 'role': ['Viewer', 'Manager', 'Admin']},
 {'user': 'jerry', 'role': ['Admin']},
 {'user': 'gill', 'role': ['Viewer', 'Manager', 'Admin']},
 {'user': 'jenny', 'role': ['Admin']}]
```

(Unless you tell it otherwise, `pprint` displays dictionary keys in alphabetized order.)

You might also be interested in [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and [enums](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

I created a dictionary which maps usernames to the dictionaries. Then I iterated over all dictionaries and update the values of the `role` list in the result dictionary.

```py
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint

d1 = [
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jim", "role": ["Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jerry", "role": ["Admin"]},
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
]

d2 = [
    {"user": "gill", "role": ["Viewer", "Manager", "Admin"]},
    {"user": "jack", "role": ["Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jim", "role": ["Viewer"]},
    {"user": "jenny", "role": ["Admin"]},
]

all_users: dict[str, dict] = {}

for d in chain(d1, d2):
    user = d["user"]
    if user in all_users:
        roles = all_users[user]["role"]
        all_users[user]["role"] = list(set(roles) | set(d["role"]))
    else:
        all_users[user] = d

pprint(all_users, sort_dicts=False)
```

output:

```
{'jack': {'user': 'jack', 'role': ['Admin', 'Viewer', 'Manager']},
 'jim': {'user': 'jim', 'role': ['Admin', 'Viewer', 'Manager']},
 'jerry': {'user': 'jerry', 'role': ['Admin']},
 'gill': {'user': 'gill', 'role': ['Admin', 'Manager', 'Viewer']},
 'jenny': {'user': 'jenny', 'role': ['Admin']}}
```

You can call `list(all_users.values())` if you don't need the usernames.

Answer (score -1):

Try for loop like this

```
# Create a dictionary to store user roles
user_roles = {}

# Merge data from data_source_1
for item in data_source_1:
    user = item["user"]
    roles = item["role"]
    if user in user_roles:
        user_roles[user].extend(roles)
    else:
        user_roles[user] = roles

# Merge data from data_source_2
for item in data_source_2:
    user = item["user"]
    roles = item["role"]
    if user in user_roles:
        user_roles[user].extend(roles)
    else:
        user_roles[user] = roles
```

Comment: Did get duplicates, but the other answers helped. Thanks!